# How to use PHP DOM to output filesize for files listed in the table of an HTML page?

Tags: php, dom, filesize, simple-html-dom

example.html (huge table that contains hundreds of files so it is impossible to list all of them as arrays):-

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file1.pdf" >Book1</a></td>
        <td class="year">2007</td>
        <td class="pages">32p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file2.pdf" >Book2</a></td>
        <td class="year">2010</td>
        <td class="pages">12p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file3.pdf" >Book3</a></td>
        <td class="year">2013</td>
        <td class="pages">42p</td>
    </tr>

   <!--------and so on... -------->
```

How to use PHP DOM to trace the filesize for file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf (and so on), to be outputed as new table data with the classname "filesize" that automatically showing __*KB(or*.__MB if larger)?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file1.pdf" >Book1</a></td>
            <td class="year">2007</td>
            <td class="pages">32p</td>
          <td class="filesize">___KB(or_.__MB if larger)</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file2.pdf" >Book2</a></td>
            <td class="year">2010</td>
            <td class="pages">12p</td>
          <td class="filesize">___KB(or_.__MB if larger)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../file3.pdf" >Book3</a></td>
            <td class="year">2013</td>
            <td class="pages">42p</td>
          <td class="filesize">___KB(or_.__MB if larger)</td>
        </tr>

   <!--------and so on... -------->
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see right now is to request each table line's file (with CURL or something similar), collect the file size in your local file system, output the new table line, delete the temp file and move on... Of course this isn't good in terms of performance, as you'll be actually downloading *every* file from the target server.

If the target server is under your control and is PHP enabled, you could implement a simple "filesize.php" script that returns this info to you, based on a parameter describing the file name (beware of security breaches, though).